# wpa_supplicant needs a manual reassociation every once in a while

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, debian, wpa-supplicant

I recently reinstalled a Debian 10 on my laptop. Before that, wireless connection to my home AP worked fine (no latency, no disconnection...).

But since the reinstallation, when my laptop is connected to an AP **sometimes, my laptop cannot reach anything through its wireless interface**.

The laptop is a **Debian 10**:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

$ uname -a
Linux XXXX 4.19.0-17-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.194-3 (2021-07-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm using **wpa_supplicant v2.8-devel** to connect to my AP and **isc-dhclient-4.4.1** to get an IP address from it.

There's no frequency for this issue. Sometimes, my laptop loses its connection in 5 minutes, sometimes no problems for hours.

When I realize that my laptop loses connection, I just execute `sudo wpa_cli reassociate` (`sudo wpa_cli reconfigure` also works) and everything starts working again.

While my laptop is "disconnected", the **wpa_supplicant** is still connected to my home AP:

```
$ sudo wpa_cli status
bssid=b0:bb:e5:aa:bb:cc
freq=5260
ssid=MY-SSID
id=0
mode=station
pairwise_cipher=CCMP
group_cipher=CCMP
key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK
wpa_state=COMPLETED
ip_address=192.168.1.47
address=f4:8c:50:aa:bb:cc
uuid=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
ieee80211ac=1
```

**iproute2** is still showing an existing IP address:

```
$ ip a s wlo1
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:8c:50:aa:bb:cc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.47/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic wlo1
       valid_lft 59381sec preferred_lft 59381sec
```

And nothing is reachable outside my home network:

```
$ ping -c4 9.9.9.9
PING 9.9.9.9 (9.9.9.9) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.47 icmp_seq=1 Destination host unreachable
From 192.168.1.47 icmp_seq=2 Destination host unreachable
From 192.168.1.47 icmp_seq=3 Destination host unreachable
From 192.168.1.47 icmp_seq=4 Destination host unreachable

--- 9.9.9.9 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 54ms pipe 4
```

Laptop still has its default gateway:

```
$ ip r
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlo1  
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.47
```

But even the AP is unreachable:

```
$ ping -c4 192.168.1.254
PING 192.168.1.254 (192.168.1.254) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.47 icmp_seq=1 Destination host unreachable
From 192.168.1.47 icmp_seq=2 Destination host unreachable
From 192.168.1.47 icmp_seq=3 Destination host unreachable
From 192.168.1.47 icmp_seq=4 Destination host unreachable

--- 9.9.9.9 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 36ms pipe 4
```

I must enter `wpa_cli` in order to reassociate the laptop to the AP:

```
$ sudo wpa_cli

wpa_cli v2.8-devel
Copyright (c) 2004-2019, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors

This software may be distributed under the terms of the BSD license.
See README for more details.


Selected interface 'wlo1'

Interactive mode

> reassociate
OK
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS 
<3>SME: Trying to authenticate with b0:bb:e5:aa:bb:cc (SSID='MY-SSID' freq=5260 MHz)
<3>Trying to associate with b0:bb:e5:aa:bb:cc (SSID='MY-SSID' freq=5260 MHz)
<3>Associated with b0:bb:e5:aa:bb:cc
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
<3>WPA: Key negotiation completed with b0:bb:e5:aa:bb:cc [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
<3>CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to b0:bb:e5:aa:bb:cc completed [id=0 id_str=]
>
```

After that, everything is working fine until the next deconnection.

But I have no idea what is the cause of this problem...

The wpa_supplicant configuration file is minimalist (and the same as before the reinstallation without the ~50 others AP configuration):

```
$ cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1
p2p_disabled=1
fast_reauth=1

network={
    ssid="MY-SSID"
    psk="XXXXX"
}
```

I start my wpa_supplicant daemon in the same way as before:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -i wlo1 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

The kernel ring buffer does not show anything interesting:

```
[64851.308454] wlo1: deauthenticating from b0:bb:e5:aa:bb:cc by local choice (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
[64851.320788] wlo1: authenticate with b0:bb:e5:aa:bb:cc
[64851.328643] wlo1: send auth to b0:bb:e5:aa:bb:cc (try 1/3)
[64851.335289] wlo1: authenticated
[64851.336970] wlo1: associate with b0:bb:e5:aa:bb:cc (try 1/3)
[64851.340532] wlo1: RX ReassocResp from b0:bb:e5:aa:bb:cc (capab=0x511 status=0 aid=69)
[64851.343218] wlo1: associated
[64851.394031] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by b0:bb:e5:aa:bb:cc
```

The first line with **deauthenticating** is caused by the reassociation through **wpa_cli**. And the last line about wlo1 (when connection is lost) does not show anything and appears long before the problem occurs.

I don't know what else to give here. And I have no idea what the problem is here...

Regarding previously made researches:

- wpa_supplicant is the only software managing my AP connections (no conflicts with NetworkManager for example)
- other devices on my AP have no problems
- if nothing is done manually, wpa_supplicant will not reassociate itself
- the laptop disconnects even if the NIC is in use
- some posts suggest to correctly set up the `REGDOMAIN` value in `/etc/default/crda`

Nothing worked. So if anyone here have an idea of what I could look for...

Or if someone have a magic trick maybe ?

Have a nice day!